# Tanach verses with narrative similar to Quran 2:61

Tags: mon-manna

I would like to ask about the following verse from the Quran 2:61 :

> And [recall] when you said, "O Moses, we can never endure one [kind
>   of] food. So call upon your Lord to bring forth for us from the earth
>   its green herbs and its cucumbers and its garlic and its lentils and
>   its onions." [Moses] said, "**Would you exchange what is better for what
>   is less? Go into [any] settlement and indeed, you will have what you
>   have asked**." And they were covered with humiliation and poverty and
>   returned with anger from Allah [upon them]. That was because they
>   [repeatedly] disbelieved in the signs of Allah and killed the prophets
>   without right. That was because they disobeyed and were [habitually]
>   transgressing.

The "one kind of food" that is being referred to here is Manna and Quails. Is there any story / verse in the Tanach that is perhaps similar to this one? In which it tells about a Jew who were requesting other food other than Manna and Quails through Moses PBUH. Because I didn't get the part about why Manna and Quails were the better food. I didn't understand how did Moses PBUH knew that they were better? In what sense were they better?**

**I'm asking from the perspective of the Tanach.

Regards,

Comment: Close voters: this doesn't look like comparative religion to me; we don't need to know anything about Islam to answer this question about Jewish sources.

Comment: I don't know about any forum in stackexchange were you can post about comparative religion...and btw my question was not about "comparing" religions. I just need to ask it here because you guys know more about the Tanach then we do..is there something wrong with doing that?

Comment: Tomsofty33 *I* don't think there's anything wrong with you asking it here.  Some people have voted to close as a "comparative religion" question (we get those sometimes); my comment is an attempt to deter more of those.  Just because a question *arises from* another religion doesn't mean it's *about* it.  That close reason is meant to apply to questions where you would have to know something about the other religion (or its texts or whatever) in order to answer the question, things like "how is the Jewish view of the messiah different from the Christian one?".  Your question isn't like that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the privilege yet to see the reason for close votes.... I misunderstood your first comment...sorry i'm still newbie

Comment: No worries, and a belated welcome.  I was addressing the people who are voting to close, not you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes [Numbers 11:4-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.11.4?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) is likely what you are looking for

> The riffraff in their midst felt a gluttonous craving; and then the
>   Israelites wept and said, “If only we had meat to eat! We remember the
>   fish that we used to eat free in Egypt, the cucumbers, the melons, the
>   leeks, the onions, and the garlic. Now our gullets are shriveled.
>   There is nothing at all! Nothing but this manna to look to!” Now the
>   manna was like coriander seed, and in color it was like bdellium. The
>   people would go about and gather it, grind it between millstones or
>   pound it in a mortar, boil it in a pot, and make it into cakes. It
>   tasted like rich cream.

Mann(a) was better because it could taste like anything you wanted it to taste (as brought by the preeminent Torah commentator Rashi on [11:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.11.5?lang=en&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.11.5.2&lang2=en)). It was a food directly handed out by God as described in [Exodus 16:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.16.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) and following.